# webpack intercept/hook into async importing

Tags: asynchronous, webpack

Webpack provides a number of ways to asynchronously load modules (`require([], resolve)`, `import('...')`, `require.ensure`). Using those functions makes webpack to automatically split resulting bundle into chunks containing required modules.

And the question is - how do I hook in whenever webpack tries to load another bundle chunk and show some loading animation (eg `nprogress.start()`) and then hide this animation (`nprogress.done()`) when the chunk is loaded?

I tried to search for webpack hooks, but all I could find was related to the compilation phase and not runtime (eg [this](https://webpack.js.org/api/plugins/compiler/#event-hooks))

Comment: I'd also love to know how to do this as well.